# footer sidebar and widget in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem related to wordpress footer widget. I created 2 custom sidebar in my twenty-thirteen theme and I add 2-2 widgets in all sidebar to show in footer. But my all widget not coming one by one, it go left.
Please help Me.

here is image of foote and widget section:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-4RKEDGwsARo/WZajbTJ60BI/AAAAAAAAAsw/VTNLuIVGHwcPr5TC0qQtp6Ctp05BiZUpQCL0BGAYYCw/h1080/2017-08-18.png

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Uq98dM3YjX8/WZajeXt-H0I/AAAAAAAAAs0/0-9xxluW-mcwxmbRuXc8T-jVPcjojI5VQCL0BGAYYCw/h1080/2017-08-18.png

Here is my code:

**Function.php**

```
function twentythirteen_widgets_init() {
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'Main Widget Area', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
    'description'   => __( 'Appears in the footer section of the site.', 
'twentythirteen' ),
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h3>',
) );

register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'Secondary Widget Area', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-2',
    'description'   => __( 'Appears on posts and pages in the sidebar.', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h3>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'Footer 1', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-3',
    'description'   => __( 'Appears on posts and pages in the sidebar.', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h3>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'Footer 2', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-4',
    'description'   => __( 'Appears on posts and pages in the sidebar.', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h3>',
) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentythirteen_widgets_init' );
```

**sidebar-main**

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
<div id="secondary" class="animated fadeInUp sidebar-container" role="complementary">
    <div class="widget-area">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 sidebar-1">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 sidebar-2">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 sidebar-3">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 sidebar-4">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-4' ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div><!-- .widget-area -->
</div><!-- #secondary -->
```

**footer**

```
        <div class="site-info ">
            <div class="container copyright">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="pull-left">&copy; 2017 SHOP</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <?php do_action( 'twentythirteen_credits' ); ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'https://wordpress.org/', 'twentythirteen' ) ); ?>" class="pull-right"><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'twentythirteen' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
    </footer><!-- #colophon -->
```

Comment: issue with div not closing properly. please check your widget content..

Comment: can you post your widget content?

Comment: I posted image link and in that image you can see in first sidebar two widget that is text, in second sidebar tow widget of recent post and woo commerce cart, in third sidebar one text that is text and in fourth sidebar two text that I used. my all widget going to left not come like below url of image:  [link]( https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-vq-6hyldBiY/WZa3FhKLn6I/AAAAAAAAAtI/Jx1D4GgkVZ8KgydODJ9Y3EFtb7hLAZ_kgCL0BGAYYCw/h1080/2017-08-18.png)

Comment: im also using same see the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMSAL.png

Comment: Please give me solution

Comment: please update your widget content and your css.

Comment: which type of css

Comment: which type of content

Comment: widget content  and your style.css.

Comment: thanks, I did it. the problem was in my code.